# "Offering RSA public key:" is not finding the correct key during ssh to my AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, pem

I am confused about what this talkback means, when I am sshing.

I feel like if I could understand it, I could solve the problem I'm having, which is, I'm getting
`debug1: No more authentication methods to try.  Permission denied (publickey).`

Here's the talkback:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xx-xx-x-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [xx.xx.x.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /me/key_B.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /me/key_Bt type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-xx-xx-x-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/me/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /me/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-xx-xx-x-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-nistp256,ecdsa-nistp384,ecdsa-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-56@libssh.org,ecdh-nistp256,ecdh-nistp384,ecdh-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-56,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa--nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-nistp521,ssh-ed25-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arc256,arc128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:OWvg35+ziszO+1muZwu+vwk8awGkedK4/N7iAy4l93A
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "me/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /me/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-xx-xx-x-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/me/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /me/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 52.43.3.81
debug1: Host 'ec2-xx-xx-x-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /me/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: me/.ssh/mobrien_mac_20161019 (0x7f9da3f00080),
debug2: key: /Users/matthewobrien/Dropbox/key_B (0x0), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
**debug1: Offering RSA public key: /me/.ssh/key_A**
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
**debug1: Trying private key: /me/key_B**
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:WAZzLsdfdsfasdfaspTYXXXXXXiS4wzvTasdfasdfTB/q0B0
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

The first bolded line show that ssh is trying to offer a private key, `key_A`. But key_A is a different key, related to a totally different server. It has nothing to do with the AWS instance I'm attempting to access.

The second bolded line is finding the correct key, `key_B`. But wait, it's a private key? This is the key I generated off the AWS console and am trying to use when I log in.

Why is ssh trying to access first a random public key, then starts looking around for a private key later? It's not finding the correct public key.

My ssh is:

`ssh -i /me/somedir/key_B.pem  ec2-user@XXXXX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Why won't ssh look in the right place?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is ssh trying to access first a random public key,

because it is most probably configured to do. What do you have in `~/.ssh/config` or in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`?

> then starts looking around for a private key later? It's not finding the correct public key.
>
> My ssh is:
>
> ```
> ssh -i /me/somedir/key_B.pem  ec2-user@XXXXX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
> ```
>
> Why won't ssh look in the right place?

```
debug1: identity file /me/key_B.pem type -1
```

because it does not understand the key. It is either in wrong format or somehow broken. How does it look like?

Comment: I have no config file at `~/.ssh`, just `authorized_keys` and `known-hosts` directories.  thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Use `-vvv` to get more verbose log. The information is probably hidden in the more verbose logs. You are looking for `IdentityFile` options, but context matters. Have a look also into the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: That took me about 10 min just to remove all the identifying info! I can't understand barely any of that talkback...what a mess...

Comment: What about the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`? The key is probably in expected format according to error (if `/me/somedir/key_B.pem` is `/me/key_B.pem`).

Comment: It says `#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa` but I am so depressed as I have no clue what this is telling me.

Comment: It starts with `#` so it is not used.

Comment: there is nothing in the file that isn't commented out!! Except `Host *
   SendEnv LANG LC_*`

Comment: Unless your `key_A` and `key_B` is `id_rsa` and `id_dsa` or similar it is impossible to happen. These are the default location for the keys. But you keep renaming them in the posted log so it is not clear what is the intention, what is typo or what is correct.

Comment: So the solution would be to move my keys somewhere? Is there some directory that ssh ONLY looks in? I thought when you used `ssh` you explicitly told it where to look for the key. Isn't that the point of the `ssh` syntax?